# Дикий лоадер при правке меток

Tags: дефект, дизайн

Собственно, вот:

> [image: скринвидео]

Comment: Какие ОС, браузер?

Comment: Подтверждаю, прямо в этом вопросе тоже воспроизводится (но у меня грузится быстро и успеть заметить это получается с трудом)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, win10, хром, но только если лоадер показывается. Если успевают загрузиться быстро, то всё хорошо.

Comment: Так это надо какое-то медленное соединение или дохлый комп?

Comment: Забавно выглядит. Сойдёт за фичу :)